# Show only weekend in jQuery datepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, datepicker

I would like the user can only select Saturdays and Sundays in my jQuery datepicker. What should I add to my datepicker script?

Comment: -1/closevote, this question does not show any research effort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function()
   {
   $('#txtDate1').datepicker({ beforeShowDay:
     function(dt)
     {
        return [dt.getDay() == 0 || dt.getDay() == 6, ""];
     }
   });
 });
```