# jquery datepicker ui - weeknds only

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, weekend

see there is a few post for this but tied  but they don't seem to work.

```
var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
```

currently my code does this and makes the weekends in active, but I would like it to do the opposite and make only the weekends active

Any idea how?

Comment: Are you sure the following solution wouldn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226543/show-only-weekend-in-jquery-datepicker-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: onlyWeekends});

function onlyWeekends(date) {
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return [false, ''];
    } else {
        return [true, ''];
    }
}
```

From the documentation: (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

```
*beforeShowDay*

A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:

[0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable 
[1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation 
[2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
```

So you can return like this:

```
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return [false, 'hilite', 'oops, this is a weekday!'];
    } else {
        return [true, 'normal', 'ok to select'];
    }
```

Comment: I didn't realise it was an array, what is noWeekend[1] for? a returned class?

Comment: @Roscoeh: Updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/05/choose-which-dates-are-selectable-in.html) appears to do exactly what you have described.